# Is there a way to Zoom in and Zoom out using react for docx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have successfully rendered docx file in browser using **react-file-viewer**. I want to add the zoom in and zoom out feature to the rendered docx files. I tried to use **react-zoom-pan-pinch** but it won't work with the docx files. It works only for images.

Here is what i tried with **react-zoom-pan-pinch**

```
splitUrl(this.state.file, 'extention') === 'docx'
    ? (
        <div className='pdf-container'>
           <TransformWrapper
            defaultScale={1}
            defaultPositionX={20}
            defaultPositionY={10}
           >
            {({ zoomIn, zoomOut, resetTransform, ...rest }) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <div className="tools">
                    <button className="fas fa-search-plus fa-2x" onClick={zoomIn}>+</button>
                    <button className="fas fa-search-minus fa-2x" onClick={zoomOut}>-</button>
                    <button className="fas fa-redo-alt fa-2x" onClick={resetTransform}>x</button>
                </div>
                <TransformComponent>
                    <div id="output-frame-id">
                        <FileViewer
                        fileType={'docx'}
                        filePath={this.state.file} //this.state.file has path of the url data
                        key={this.state.file}
                        allowFullScreen={true}
                        />
                    </div>
                </TransformComponent>
             </React.Fragment>
           )}
        </TransformWrapper>                                                 
   </div>
```

It only works for img i guess becz when i added this i cannot scroll down into the docx file.

Is there any other way to add zoom in and zoom out to docx files in react.